# How to prefill checkout page of instamojo email field , name field, and phone number field via js seamless checkout

Tags: javascript

I am using seamless checkout of instamojo payment gateway. I want prefill the field of checkout form you can see mentioned image.

[image]

I have trid via this code but only purpose & amount is supporting

```
Instamojo.open("https://test.instamojo.com/@zishanaltamash246/?&purpose=buying&amount=450&email=test@gmail.com");
```

How can I prefill name , email, phone ?